# Can you use the same workflow id in different domains in Cadence?

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

Is it possible to register a Cadence workflow with the same workflow ID in different domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, workflow ID uniqueness is enforced per/within a domain